# Bipolar oblique projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to implement the [bipolar oblique projection](https://proj.org/operations/projections/bipc.html) in QGIS. I've created the custon CRS as:
+proj=bipc  +ns +lon_0=0 +x_0=1000000 +y=1000000 +datum=WGS84
The result, however, is incorrect. As the screenshot shows, the features are skewed where I believe both sectors of the projection connect. The problem occurs with the polygons as well as the much simpler geometry of the grid I made with "Create grid".
[image]

Comment: Bipolar oblique is not a well-behaved projection due to having to link up 2 conic projections. You'd probably have to ask the PROJ people about what's going on.